# Storing data from a text file to a dictionary with keys

Tags: dictionary, import

branching off from my previous question. How can i import data from a text file and then store it in a dictionary with a specific key such as:

there is a space between each username and password but they appear directly below each other on text file

Text file:

username,password

user2,password2

user3,password3

into a dictionary in python as follows:

`Database = {username: password,user2: password2,user3: password3}` 
which i can then use in a log in validificator to confirm wheter both username and password is correct

Answer (score 0):

So you have a user/pwd pair per line? You can loop through the lines of your files and split with `,`:

```py
db = {}
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        words = l.strip().split(',')
        if len(words) > 1: # only considering lines with at least one comma
            db[words[0]] = words[1]
```